# Neo4j How to Create Multiple Lists From Values in Nested JSON

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I have this JSON Data:

```
{"title": "Title1", "authors": [{"name": "Dave Chappelle", "org": "MIT"}], "id": "abc123"}
{"title": "Title2", "authors": [{"name": "Rick Sanchez"}, {"name": "Amy Schumer"], "id": "xyz234"}
```

And I want to create some information that looks like:

`[“author1”, “author2",... “authorN”]` for every paper in the JSON file.

For example, with the first line of data, the list would just be `["Dave Chappelle"]`

The second line of data the list would be `["Rick Sanchez, "Amy Schumer"]`

Once I have this, I want to do some Cypher operations using each of these lists. Specifically, I want to create a relationship between each author in a paper and a paper, with the `AUTHORED` relationship having two properties, `is_first_author` and `is_last_author` with boolean values.

For a single piece of data in the JSON file, I know the following works to identify elements in a given list and gives a boolean value for if each element is the first or last:

```
WITH [“author1”, “author2", “author3”, “author4"] AS authors
UNWIND range(0,size(authors)-1,1) as idx
return idx, authors[idx], idx=1 AS is_first_author, idx=size(authors)-1 as is_last_author
```

and returns

```
idx authors[idx]    is_first_author is_last_author
0   "author1"   false   false
1   "author2"   true    false
2   "author3"   false   false
3   "author4"   false   true
```

In order get this list of authors and add these properties to the relationship between each author and their paper, I'm using the following code:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file.txt') YIELD value AS q UNWIND q.id AS id UNWIND q.authors as authors
MERGE (i:Quanta {id:q.id}) 
MERGE (a:Author {name:authors.name})
FOREACH (quanta IN q.id | WITH quanta.authors as authors 
WITH collect(authors.name) as names 
UNWIND range(0,size(names)-1,1) as idx 
MERGE (a)-[:AUTHORED {is_first_author:idx=1}, {is_last_author: idx=size(authors)-1}]-(i)
            RETURN *;
```

However, this gives me a syntax error:

```
Invalid input ',': expected whitespace or ']' (line 4, column 177 (offset: 380))
"FOREACH (quanta IN q.id | WITH quanta.authors as authors WITH collect(authors.name) as names UNWIND range(0,size(names)-1,1) as idx MERGE (a)-[:AUTHORED {is_first_author:idx=1}, {is_last_author: idx=size(authors)-1}]-(i)"
```

I am also fairly certain that using a `WITH` statement inside of the `FOREACH` is not syntactically valid, but I'm not quite sure how to do this otherwise.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the list already, you can get the first and last author by `head(list)` and `last(list)`, do that before you unwind the list, save the comparison, then use it at the end.

Also, according to your data, the `id` property isn't a list, so there's no need to unwind it. Only use UNWIND on lists, since it converts them to rows

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file.txt') YIELD value AS q 
WITH q.id AS id, head(q.authors).name as firstName, last(q.authors).name as lastName, q.authors as authors
UNWIND authors as author
MERGE (i:Quanta {id:id}) 
MERGE (a:Author {name:author.name})
WITH i, a, author.name = firstName as isFirstName, author.name = lastName as isLastName
MERGE (a)-[:AUTHORED {is_first_author:isFirstName, is_last_author:isLastName}]-(i)
RETURN *;
```

Note that if there is only a single author then it will be registered as both first and last author.

Also, if there are any duplicate names in the list, that may throw off the results, but I doubt the data will have duplicate names per Quanta.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! I will say that while ID itself is not a list we were using it to unwind the list of all papers using the ID property. Maybe I was thinking about this the wrong way, but it has seemed to work so far.